# Gemfire continuous query clients in hot-hot mode?

Tags: java, gemfire

So I know Gemfire has high availability when it comes to the server side i.e., if a server that was streaming events to a continuous query client crashes, the secondary instance of the server will pick up from where the primary left off. In other words, the subscription queue for durable clients are synced among the servers.

1) But does anyone know if it is possible to do the same with the continuous query clients? To elaborate, if a client C1 fails, client C2, which was on standby, starts to receive events from the cache. Is there a way to configure Gemfire to treat its clients in this way?

2) Alternatively, can I have two clients C1 and C2 subscribed to a region A for continuous query updates and either C1 or C2 receives an event E1? The event will not be streamed to both the clients but to the one client that was randomly chosen by Gemfire. In effect, the two clients behave as if they are connected to a queue.

I understand in 2), I could simply publish the events to a queue and get the same effect but I am curious to see if Gemfire can be tuned his way.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure durable CQs such that if a client fails(stops) and later returns back, nothing is lost. Server will store the CQ events in a queue and when the client restarts/reconnects it will re-send them to the client.
If C1 and C2 have configured CQ then both will receive CQ events. I don' think there is a way you can have something like events streamed to only 1 client out of the 2.